# VBA Wait for DoCmd.RunSQL OR Better Query - Ms Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query which uses an array of tables (stored as a string array) to loop through my tables and perform a Delete/Update set of queries. The queries are identical other than the table names, hence using a loop to iterate through using the table name as a variable.

The problem is, my Delete query locks the table and the Update query runs too quickly afterward; I get a "db is locked" error.

I need either of two things:

1. A way to tell VBA to "wait for previous command" OR
2. A way to concatenate these queries into one (or two) queries: one to delete the database rows and another to import the new ones. With this I could just run the queries from a standard access query (which should allocate proper time, finish queries etc)

The only catch to this is that there are parent-child relations, so the parent table has to be updated before its children (currently accomplished through array ordering).

Here's the current code which (sometimes) produces the "DB locked/in use" message:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(tables)
    'Delete all data first
    sql = "DELETE * FROM " & tables(i)
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
    'Update all data second
    sql = "INSERT INTO " & tables(i) & " IN """ & toDB & """ SELECT " & tables(i) & " .* FROM " & tables(i) & " IN """ & fromDB & """;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
Next
```

Should clarify: the queries take one backend's (`fromDB`) rows from identical tables and pushes it to another backend's (`toDB`) rows

EDIT: In response to the questions regarding `INSERT INTO`, my problem with that is if I add fields to the `toDB`, it will delete them if I overwrite. The reason I have to do this backdoor approach is because the database is still in development, but is also being used with select tables. Updates and feature improvements are done daily. I cannot use a simple split-backend either, because the other computer accessing the database is not always on the network (we have to manually sync it when it returns to the network), so I work on one backend and it works on another, identical(ish, minus my schema update) backend.

Comment: You should be using `CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

Comment: Works, and I assume is the better practice, but I still run into the same error.. maybe I have to add a "wait until __ not locked" sort of statement instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADO instead of DoCmd.RunSQL to execute your SQL synchronously.

```
 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
 Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection

 Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection

 For i = 0 To UBound(tables)
     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     With cmd

        .CommandType = adCmdText
         .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandText = "DELETE * FROM " & tables(i)
        .Execute
      End With

     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     With cmd

        .CommandType = adCmdText
         .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & tables(i) & " IN """ & toDB & """ SELECT " & tables(i) & " .* FROM " & tables(i) & " IN """ & fromDB & """;"
        .Execute
      End With

Next
```

You could also add `cnn.BeginTrans` and `cnn.CommitTrans` to make the two statements Atomic.

Comment: Likely a newbie question, but VBA doesn't recognize the ADODB objects. Do I need to set something somewhere to allow this object?

Comment: You'll need to add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Object" using Tools->References. However you might consider trying `CurrentDb.Execute` as HK1 commented

Comment: Error: basically saying that `cnn` in your above is not a valid OLE DB Session object.

Comment: Sorry about that check my edit it should be `Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection`

Comment: I think that's got it. Your edit may have been a problem, but wasn't the problem with the error given (my last comment). I think it had to do with the references, as the code builder didn't recognize ADODB as a command; the auto-complete context menus weren't showing up. I added the references, restarted Access and it found the .Command, .CommandType etc. Tried with your edit and it's all up and going now; havn't been able to replicate my original error using this method. Seems good!

Comment: See http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=157367 for the references.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (Note I've commented your `DoCmd.RunSQL`. I changed it with `db.Execute`:

```
Sub DeleteInsertData(tables() As String, toDB As String, fromDB As String)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SQL As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    For i = 0 To UBound(tables)
        'Delete all data first
        SQL = "DELETE * FROM " & tables(i)
        db.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
        'DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
        'Update all data second
        SQL = "INSERT INTO " & tables(i) & " IN """ & toDB & """ SELECT " & tables(i) & " .* FROM " & tables(i) & " IN """ & fromDB & """;"
        db.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
        'DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    Next
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: DAO is faster than ADO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I don't think you need the DELETE part.  SELECT INTO is the syntax for making a table.  If the table already exists, it's overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to wait for something, I tend to use `DoEvents` to allow windows to process any other actions that have been put on hold.
From the help: "Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events."

Found this:
`.BeginTrans` then
`.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush`
as a way to force updates to be written before continuing

Comment: The same error occurs even when using DoEvents. Is there a reason why the backend is being locked for slightly longer than is necessary? Surely with all the changes suggested here, the query is running fully. Why is the backend staying locked?

Comment: seems buffers need to be flushed - I added the info to my answer